# Can't login to Django Admin with custom user and Mezzanine/South

Tags: python, django, admin, django-south, mezzanine

I have django app with a custom user like this:

```
import ...

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


# # Person (representation of people)


class AbstractPerson(models.Model):
    """
    ABSTRACT model representing basic information about a person on the platform,
    be it a user or a person used in acts he's generating.
    """

    MALE = 'M'
    FEMALE = 'F'
    GIRL = 'G'
    FRENCH_TITLES = (
        (MALE, 'M.'),
        (FEMALE, 'Mme'),
        (GIRL, 'Mlle'),
    )

    date_created = models.DateTimeField(_('date created'),
                                        default=timezone.now,
                                        db_index=True)

    title = models.CharField(u'Civilité', max_length=1,
                             choices=FRENCH_TITLES,
                             blank=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(u'Prénom', max_length=500, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(u'Nom', max_length=500, blank=True,
                                 db_index=True)
    phone = models.CharField(u'Téléphone', max_length=10, blank=True)
    address_1 = models.CharField(u'Adresse', max_length=200, blank=True)
    address_2 = models.CharField(u"Complément d'adresse", max_length=200,
                                 blank=True, null=True)
    zipcode = models.CharField(u'Code Postal', max_length=10, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(u'Ville', max_length=50, blank=True)


    class Meta:
        abstract = True


# # Auth

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """Replacement for django auth's UserManager"""

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')
        email = UserManager.normalize_email(email)

        now = timezone.now()

        user = self.model(email=email,
                          is_staff=False, is_active=True, is_superuser=False,
                          last_login=now, date_created=now, **extra_fields)

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        u = self.create_user(email, password=password, **extra_fields)
        u.is_staff = True
        u.is_active = True
        u.is_superuser = True
        u.save(using=self._db)
        return u


class User(AbstractPerson, AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    """
    Replacement for django.contrib.auth's User.
    Gets basic Person information injected from AbstractPerson
    """

    # Regular fields
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), max_length=255,
                              unique=True, db_index=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(_('staff status'), default=False,
                                   help_text=_('Designates whether the user '
                                               'can log into this admin site.'))
    is_active = models.BooleanField(_('active'), default=True,
                                    help_text=_('Designates whether the user '
                                                'should be treated as active. '
                                                'Unselect this instead of '
                                                'deleting accounts.'))

    # Compatibility with Mezzanine accounts app
    username = models.EmailField(_('username (copy of email address)'),
                                 max_length=255,
                                 unique=True, db_index=True)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []  # Nothing required apart from email


    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('user')
        verbose_name_plural = _('users')
    abstract = False

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.username = self.email
        try: kwargs.pop('username')
        except KeyError: pass
        super(User, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Then my settings are:

```
# Custom user model
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'useraccount.User'

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'grappelli',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.comments',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    "django.contrib.redirects",
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    "django.contrib.sites",
    "django.contrib.sitemaps",
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    "storages",          # django-storages backend
    ## Custom user model and such
    'useraccount',
    ## Mezzanine
    "mezzanine.boot",
    "mezzanine.conf",
    "mezzanine.core",
    "mezzanine.generic",
    #"mezzanine.blog",
    "mezzanine.forms",
    "mezzanine.pages",
    #"mezzanine.galleries",
    #"mezzanine.twitter",
    #"mezzanine.accounts",
    #"mezzanine.mobile",
    'south',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    "mezzanine.core.request.CurrentRequestMiddleware",
    "mezzanine.core.middleware.RedirectFallbackMiddleware",
    "mezzanine.core.middleware.TemplateForDeviceMiddleware",
    "mezzanine.core.middleware.TemplateForHostMiddleware",
    "mezzanine.core.middleware.AdminLoginInterfaceSelectorMiddleware",
    "mezzanine.core.middleware.SitePermissionMiddleware",
    # Uncomment the following if using any of the SSL settings:
    #"mezzanine.core.middleware.SSLRedirectMiddleware",
    "mezzanine.pages.middleware.PageMiddleware",
    "mezzanine.core.middleware.FetchFromCacheMiddleware",
)
```

So now with that, I've synced the db and created a superuser. In the shell, everything look good:

```
In [1]: from useraccount.models import User

In [2]: from django.contrib.auth import authenticate

In [3]: authenticate(username='john', password='secret')
Out[3]: <User: john>

In [4]: u = User.objects.all()[0]

In [5]: u.is_active
Out[5]: True

In [6]: u.is_staff
Out[6]: True

In [7]: u.is_superuser
Out[7]: True
```

And with all that, impossible to connect to the admin... Admin doesn't say: 
    `Please enter the correct email address and password for a staff account. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive.`

But:
    `Please correct the error below.`

Any idea?

**EDIT**

Sorry, I didn't precised that I used MezzanineBackend to authenticate the user:

`AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ("mezzanine.core.auth_backends.MezzanineBackend",)`

The code is this:

```
class MezzanineBackend(ModelBackend):

def authenticate(self, **kwargs):
    if kwargs:
        username = kwargs.pop("username", None)
        if username:
            username_or_email = Q(username=username) | Q(email=username)
            password = kwargs.pop("password", None)
            try:
                user = User.objects.get(username_or_email, **kwargs)
            except User.DoesNotExist:
                pass
            else:
                if user.check_password(password):
                    return user
        else:
            if 'uidb36' not in kwargs:
                return
            kwargs["id"] = base36_to_int(kwargs.pop("uidb36"))
            token = kwargs.pop("token")
            try:
                user = User.objects.get(**kwargs)
            except User.DoesNotExist:
                pass
            else:
                if default_token_generator.check_token(user, token):
                    return user
```

Maybe the problem is that there is no get_user method, so I'll try this and come back if it doesn't work

**EDIT2**

No changes with the get_user method added... Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so it was django-grappelli which messed up my admin. I changed it for grappelli_safe and everything is good now :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is coming from the fact that your new user model, though registered into settings.py doesn't have an authentication backend associated. Thus has no way he could be authenticated in your app.

Following this tutorial : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/ you should have a file looking like this :

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, check_password

class SettingsBackend(object):
"""
Authenticate against the settings ADMIN_LOGIN and ADMIN_PASSWORD.

Use the login name, and a hash of the password. For example:

ADMIN_LOGIN = 'admin'
ADMIN_PASSWORD = 'sha1$4e987$afbcf42e21bd417fb71db8c66b321e9fc33051de'
"""

def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
    login_valid = (settings.ADMIN_LOGIN == username)
    pwd_valid = check_password(password, settings.ADMIN_PASSWORD)
    if login_valid and pwd_valid:
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(username=username)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            # Create a new user. Note that we can set password
            # to anything, because it won't be checked; the password
            # from settings.py will.
            user = User(username=username, password='get from settings.py')
            user.is_staff = True
            user.is_superuser = True
            user.save()
        return user
    return None

def get_user(self, user_id):
    try:
        return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        return None
```

Registered this way in `settings.py`:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS ('mybackend',)
```

You may also need an `admin.py` file overriding `django.contrib.auth.admin.UserAdmin`
Which you can then register

```
 admin.site.register(get_user_model(), YourUserAdmin)
```

To be able to see it in the admin console.

PS is_staff and is_superuser should be callables, not booleans